# Is there a way to use inspect element to select an element in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm looking to utilize the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" `Ctrl + Shift + C` utility in Chromium's developer tools in order to allow a user to select an element on an Electron application.

For example, a page or file should be loaded. Then, upon calling a function, the user should be presented with the ability to select an element as if they had opened their developer tools and pressed the inspect element button. Clicking on an element to inspect it should result in a function being called with the inspected element, without opening the developer tools. The intention is that this is a built in way to select elements on a page without the need for re-writing code to allow for this style of point, highlight, and click selection system.

The intended usage is as follows

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

app.on('ready', function() {
    let window = new BrowserWindow();
    window.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');


    // This should trigger the inspect element tool
    window.getElementFromInspector(function(element) {
        // This should be called after an element is selected with the inspect element tool
    });
});
```

It's not expected that window should necessarily contain a `.getElementFromInspector(callback: function)` method. However, the solution should be functionally similar to the proposed usage. (Even if it requires loading external JavaScript into the page, just was trying to avoid it if at all possible)

Doing some looking in Electon's API documentation gave light to the `contents.inspectElement(x, y)` method. This sounds as if it would allow for an element to be selected for inspection from an x,y position on the page, but mentions nothing of accessing the now inspected element remotely. I would also imagine this results in opening the developer tools if not already open, which is something that can hopefully be avoided.

**EDIT:** From what I've seen, I don't believe it is going to be <s>possible</s> easy to use the inspect element selector without having the developer tools open. Because of this, answers that require the developer tools to be open will be accepted, but it is preferred that the developer tools need not be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes the inspect on hover over in the same way the inspect element utility does, but does not highlight the element. It also requires the developer tools to be shown to work.

```
// main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

electron.app.on('ready', function() {
  let window = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'inspector.js')
    }
  });

  window.webContents.openDevTools();

  electron.ipcMain.addListener('mouse', function(event, e) {
    event.returnValue = null;
    window.webContents.inspectElement(e.x, e.y);
  });

  window.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');
});
```

```
// inspector.js
window.onload = function() {
  let {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

  document.onmousemove = e => ipcRenderer.sendSync('mouse', { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};
```

This doesn't do exactly what I had wanted, nor does it do it in the manor I had intended, but it is the closest I've been able to get to solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Good News!** Here a very clean solution for this.I totally understand what particular problem you're facing.

**Install Electron Context Menu**

If you're using Npm ([learn more about NPM here](https://www.npmjs.com/))

```
npm install electron-context-menu
```

Otherwise using yarn [(learn more about Yarn here)](https://yarnpkg.com/)

```
  yarn add electron-context-menu
```

**STEP 1: Learning how the Context Menu works**

```
// ./main.js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const contextMenu = require('electron-context-menu');

// Add an item to the context menu that appears only when you click on an image
contextMenu({
    prepend: (params, browserWindow) => [{
        label: 'Rainbow',
        // Only show it when right-clicking images
        visible: params.mediaType === 'image'
    }]
});

// Your code that starts a new application
let win;
(async () => {
    await app.whenReady();
    win = new BrowserWindow();
})();
```

**STEP2: Adding items to the context menu with a custom behaviour**

```
const contextMenu = require('electron-context-menu');

contextMenu({
    prepend: (params, browserWindow) => [
        {
            label: 'Destroy Atomic Bombs',
            click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
                // Note that the alert function is only avaialble in the renderer process
                //alert("You destroyed all the atomic bombs in the world, thanks :3")

                // If executed from the main process, the console log function will appear in the terminal, not in the developer tools
                console.log("You destroyed all the atomic bombs in the world, thanks :3")
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

detail learning for this method -  [Way 1](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/874/how-to-implement-a-native-context-menu-with-inspect-element-in-electron-framework)
[Github repo of electron-context-menu](https://github.com/MuhammadUmairghufran/electron-context-menu)

I hope, it will help you :) Happy coding.

Comment: From my understanding, this will allow for the creation of custom context menu items such as changing to dark theme or other page/element specific functions. However, the intent was more to highlight elements as the user hovers over them until they left click to select. Something along the lines of [this](https://prnt.sc/sp3zgo), without the box containing details or color variance in the element shading. Is electron-context-menu capable of doing this?

Comment: Yes, I Beleive so,

Comment: I was unable to find a way to activate the inspect element _"mode"_ using electron-context-menu. The closest I have gotten is using IPC and `contents.inspectElement`, but this doesn't require anything more than just Electron itself.

Comment: You say to inbox you, but I'm not sure what you mean. Stack Exchange has never, and most likely will never, support direct messaging between users. If you are able to do what I have asked, please edit your answer to reflect the method you have used to do so, as others who view this question might be wondering how to do the same thing, thanks!

Comment: Yeah ok i got it. Did you follow github repo documentation .. there a option inspect elements you can add inspect element on right click in your electron application

Comment: Yes, there is a way to add a context option to allow for inspecting an element that has been right clicked on. This is not what I am asking for. The intended result is that the user is placed into the inspect element utility as if they had pressed `Ctrl+Shift+C` without the need for any user input. Not to add the ability to inspect an element with right click.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for me: **(Right click + Shift at Element)**

main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('InspectMeAtPos', (ev, cursorPos) => { 
    let senderWd = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(ev.sender)
    console.log('InspectMeAtPos : ', cursorPos)
    senderWd.webContents.inspectElement(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y)
})
```

preload.js:

```
addEventListener('contextmenu', (ev) => {
  ev.shiftKey ? ipc.send('InspectMeAtPos', { x: ev.x, y: ev.y }) : null
})
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. While I'm glad you found a solution to your problem I don't think this answers my question. It looks like it would just inspect any element you `Shift + Right Click` on. I was looking to be able to get a colorful box around an element so the user could see what they were selecting. Then pass that element back so I could do something with it, all without opening Inspect Element. Either way, I haven't worked on this project in some time now and do not foresee picking it up again. Hope your answer helps others.

Answer (score 0):

As Muhammad said, I also used 'electron-context-menu' like this:

1. npm install electron-context-menu
2. I use it in electron, react with typescript like:

**main.ts** - at the top of the file:

```
import contextMenu from "electron-context-menu";

contextMenu({
  showSaveImageAs: true,
  showInspectElement: true,
});

let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow | null;

(async () => {
  await app.whenReady();

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      spellcheck: true,
    },
  });
})();
```